# Something similar to an if/elseif statement, in JavaScript to edit the HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Pretty new programmer here, working on a small website project for school.

I managed, with help, to get the themes (top left corner) to work, but it only changes the color of the background so far, and I want it to change for example colors of borders around the buttons on the page, and edit classes in css in general.

Is there any way to do this? This is the current solution, and as you see, there is no way to make for example the background gray and the borders of buttons blue at once, with one `<option>`

```
    <select id="select" onchange="javascript:changeColor(this);">
        <option disabled hidden>Theme</option>
        <optgroup label="Themes"></optgroup>
        <option value="white">Light</option>
        <option value="#222222">Dark</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
    </select>

var theme = window.localStorage.theme;
changeColor.value = theme;
changeColor();
function changeColor(el) {
    if (el) theme = window.localStorage.theme = el.value;
    document.body.style.background = theme;
}
```

What I need is something like: `If (option == light) { .button border-color: #222, .textbutton color: orange;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your theme so that you had classes as values:

```
<select id="select" onchange="javascript:changeTheme(this);">
    <option disabled hidden>Theme</option>
    <optgroup label="Themes"></optgroup>
    <option value="white">Light</option>
    <option value="dark">Dark</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Then your onchange function can add that class to your body:

```
var theme = window.localStorage.theme === 'undefined' ? 'white' : window.localStorage.theme;  // set theme to stored theme or default (in this case default is white)
document.body.className = theme; // change class
document.getElementById('select').value = theme; // set select to current stored theme

function changeColor(el) {
    if (el && el.value != '') {
       theme = window.localStorage.theme = el.value; // set theme to new value
    }

    document.body.className = theme; // change class
}
```

This way you can use css to define your styles:

```
.white #select {
   background:#ffffff;
}

.red #select {
   background:#ff0000;
}

.dark #select {
   background:#cccccc;
}
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qraasLt/1)

Comment: Or example with multiple items changing: https://jsfiddle.net/9qraasLt/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#select").val() == "red") {
    $(".button").css("border-color","#222");
}
```

Comment: And this can me used normally in javascript file instead of my current code?

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare three themes in css like this:

```
.theme-light .btn{
   //style for btn
}
.theme-dark .btn{
   //style for btn      
}
.theme-red .btn{ 
  //style for btn
}
```

when `select` changed change classname of `body`

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript solution - tested in the console of your website and it works.

First you should select the values of the options. 
That be can done by selecting your '**select**' element by its id, for example you can set an **id 'select'**, and after that you can select the option value by its index. 
You can also add ids to your buttons in order to select them, and different classes for their borders, text, .etc., which will be applied after a certain condition is met. For example, for the HTML button, it can be '**btnHtml**'.

In your function:

```
function changeColor(el) {
if (el) theme = window.localStorage.theme = el.value;
document.body.style.background = theme;

var getSelect = document.getElementById('select');
var option = getSelect.options[getSelect.selectedIndex].value;
var btnHtml = document.getElementById('btnHtml');

if(option === 'light'){
    btnHtml.className += 'light';
 }

else if (option === 'dark') {
 btnHtml.className += 'dark';
}

else if (option === 'red') {
 btnHtml.className += 'red';
}
```

}

Also, you don't need to call the function in your html like this:

```
onchange="javascript:changeColor(this);"
```

just write

```
onchange="changeColor(this);"
```

In your CSS file, make some classes for your buttons. For example, you can make

```
.red {
  border-color: red;
}
```

And respectively other classes for the other button borders appearances. Hope it helps.